# import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; no documentation for package

Tags: dart, flutter

I see this import statement in many examples but can't find any documentation for the package anywhere.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation about flutter/foundation is available [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/foundation-library.html)

> foundation library
>
> Core Flutter framework primitives.
>
> The features defined in this library are the lowest-level utility classes and functions used by all the other layers of the Flutter framework.

Comment: hmm, thanks. The thing is, I see it in some example code and not in others. If all the lowest-level classes use it, then it must be included regardless right? Is it one of those things that can be ommitted but are implicitly included anyway?

Comment: Yeah other packages usually re-export some of the lower layer stuff.

Comment: do you mean re-import ? Meaning not including this like will make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Update: New link to `flutter/foundation` documentation
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/foundation-library.html